# How to see a code generated by scala compiler

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, code-generation

I'm new to Scala. I use IntelliJ Idea Community Edition.

I know that it's possible to see Java code generated by Scala compiler:

1. Using javap (or any other decompiler)
2. Or using `scalac MyClass.scala -print` command

How to see that code directly in IDE without copy-pasting it each time from console?

Comment: There is no Java source code generated, but bytecode. What's the goal?

Comment: My goal is to get deep understanding of implementation details  of different Scala's features.

Comment: I don't think trying to disasemble would be very helpful. Scala specs and tutorials would be better for me.